# Which wp plugin can use Create, Edit and Delete Email address from Wordpress Dashboard

Tags: plugin-development

I have multiple websites on my Cpanel and I want each client to be able to create, edit and update their email address on their WordPress dashboard without seeing each other's email addresses.

How do I go about it?

Comment: Can't they update their email addresses in the normal admin site under Settings, General, Administration Email Address? Or is this some other email address in cpanel? If it's in cpanel then that's not something we can help with sorry - you'll probably have to talk to your host.

Comment: Do they even have access to your cpanel? If they do then I'd assume it's already locked down to their own pages and settings only.